# How to use smartystreets with python

Tags: python, geolocation, smartystreets

I've installed smartystreets:

```
pip install smartystreets.py
```

In the documentation page 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smartystreets.py/0.2.1

Thaey have this:

Create a client instance with your key:

```
client = SmartyStreets(AUTH_ID, AUTH_TOKEN)
```

but I get this error:

```
name 'SmartyStreets' is not defined
```

If I try:

```
import SmartyStreets
```

I get:

```
No module named SmartyStreets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the documentation at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smartystreets.py isn't as current as the documentation at https://github.com/bennylope/smartystreets.py. Try this instead:

```
from smartystreets import Client
client = Client(AUTH_ID, AUTH_TOKEN)
```